# Insert specific element y after every n elements in a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm teaching myself Haskell and I've run across the question in my book that ask me to define a function insert that takes a positive integer `n`, element `y`, and a list `xs` that inserts the specified element `y` after every `n` elements in the list.

I believe pattern matching would probably be a good way to go but I've yet to really grasp what it means

```
insert :: Int -> Char -> [a] -> [a]
insert 0 y xs = xs
insert n y [] = []
insert n y (x:xs)
```

An example of how the function should work:

```
insert 2 'X' "abcdefghijk" = "abXcdXefXghXijXk"
```

I've taken care of the base cases at this point but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `insert 2 'X' "abcdefghijk" = "abXcdXefXghXijXk"`
I meant this (sorry i was typing fast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a helper function that counts down and resets when it gets to zero.

```
insert :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insert n y xs = countdown n xs where
   countdown 0 xs = y:countdown n xs -- reset to original n
   countdown _ [] = []
   countdown m (x:xs) = x:countdown (m-1) xs
```

What behaviour do you want if it's time to insert at the end? 
Here I've prioritised inserting over finishing by putting `countdown 0 xs` before `countdown _ []`.
How could you rewrite it if you wanted to skip the insert at the end?

Sample usage:

```
*Main> insert 3 '|' "Hello Mum, erm... can I borrow £20000 please?"
"Hel|lo |Mum|, e|rm.|.. |can| I |bor|row| £2|000|0 p|lea|se?|"
```

Comment: well this particular question asks for an element specifically a character. I ran your function and it throws me errors. Why is that?

Comment: @NuNu What errors did you get? I'll paste a sample call in case that helps.

Comment: If you want it to only work with characters, you could change the type singature to be `insert :: Int -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]`, which is the same as `insert :: Int -> Char -> String -> String`.

Answer (score 6):

In the last case, take n elements of the list, insert a singleton list of y and then append the result of recursively calling the function after dropping first n elements of the list.

```hs
insert :: Int -> Char -> [a] -> [a]
insert 0 y xs = xs
insert n y [] = []
insert n y xs
 | length xs < n = xs
 | otherwise = take n xs ++ [y] ++ insert n y (drop n xs)
```

Comment: @AndrewC, given that the OP is just starting to learn Haskell, I think this answer is the simplest and hence best.

Comment: It is simple, yes, and helpful. And `drop`, `take` and `length` are important functions to introduce to the OP. (I didn't downvote, by the way.)

Comment: @AndrewC Isn't this the okay direction for `(++)`? This should be no less efficient (asymptotically) than manually counting the way you suggested. `(++)` only gets really bad when it's associated to the left.

Comment: Oooooops. I've let my own past mistakes mislead me - many years ago now, my second real-need haskell program analysed a vast number of polynomials for a property we were seeking for a research task. I used `++` the bad, left-associative way and ran out of memory on the department's biggest unix server before writing a line of data to the output files! Abhinav is _not_ making the same mistake, you're right Daniel, so I deleted my original comment because it's [wrong](http://xkcd.com/386/). I'm ashamed of myself. If I had a second upvote I would use it by way of apology.

Comment: The downvotes just keep coming without any reasons. What is wrong with this solution? It is correct, simple and it run in linear time which the best you can get.

Comment: repeatedly measuring `length` is a quadratic behaviour. also, it *diverges* for infinite lists. that must have been the reason, I gather. so yeah, this really isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's OK to use library functions to your advantage.

```
import Data.List

insertAtN n y xs = intercalate [y] . groups n $ xs
  where
    groups n xs = takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n) $ xs
```

Of course if you insert `Char` into list of type `[a]` then `a` is `Char`, because in Haskell all elements of a list are of same type.

---

To help you understand this on a more immediate level, let's first look at just making a copy of a list:

```
copyList (x:xs) = x : copyList xs
copyList [] = []
```

Now imagine you add index value to each element being copied (re-implementing `zip xs [1..]`):

```
copyIdxList xs = go 1 xs where
  go i (x:xs) = (x,i) : go (i+1) xs
  go _ [] = []
```

Now that we have an index value when we're dealing with each element, we can use it and, say, put each 10-th element of a list *twice* into the result:

```
copyIdxTenthTwice xs = go 1 xs where
  go i (x:xs) | i==10 = (x,i) : (x,i) : go 1 xs
  go i (x:xs)         = (x,i) : go (i+1) xs
  go _ [] = []
```

See where I'm going with this? Instead of duplicating the `x`, you can insert `y` there. And you don't have to put the indices into the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
ins n y xs = zip xs (cycle [1..n]) >>= f where
  f (x,k) = if k == n then [x,y] else [x]
```

The `zip` part attaches cyclic "indexes" to the elements of the list, e.g. for `n = 3` and `xs = "abcdefg"` we get `[('a',1),('b',2)('c',3)('d',1)('e',2)('f',3)('g',1)]`. Now `(>>=)` (which is the same as `concatMap` in case of lists) uses `f` to map every pair back to the original element, except when we have the last index of a cycle: In that case we insert an additional divider element `y` as well.